# How do i get relative dimensions of scrollbale window viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a Tooltip (larger image view) that is being positioned via e.pageX e.pageY and i am trying to make sure it is not hidden below the current scrolled view port.

I have seen many sites have this
my code is something like this but i am missing something.

```
var positionImg = function(e) {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width(); 
    var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();  
    var mouseAtY = e.pageY;
    var mouseAtX = e.pageX;
    var maxBottomVPos = viewportHeight-"i dont know";
    var maxTopVPos = 30;

    if (mouseAtY >= maxBottomVPos)
    {
        tPosX = mouseAtX+ 10;
        tPosY = mouseAtY -520;
    }
    else if (mouseAtY <= maxTopVPos)
    {
        tPosX = mouseAtX;
        tPosY = mouseAtY +40;
    }
    else
    {
        tPosX = mouseAtX;
        tPosY = mouseAtY +20;  
    }
    $zoomContainer.css({top: tPosY, left: tPosX});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `var maxBottomVPos = viewportHeight-"i dont know";`

You probably don't want to go any lower than the height of the element that you are positioning. So use the height of `zoomContainer` to figure out how much higher it needs to go. This way, the whole thing can be included. Of course, you'll have to consider that the user might shrink the screen too small to fit the container.

To get the scroll offset use [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop). With this you will have both the size of the viewport and how far down the viewport is.

Comment: You are correct, but my question is "how do i get the current vewport of the screen when the body is scrolled" 
view image http://img.skitch.com/20090708-njwmg2fmrx23w6m8yau5axmn95.png

Comment: you already have the viewport height. i think i know what you mean, do you need the scrolled offset?

Comment: "To get the scroll offset use scrollTop." in my case what will the formula be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Quite simple:
var positionImg = function(e) {
            cntnrH = $zoomContainer.height() + 230;
            calHight = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() + cntnrH;
            docH = $(window).height()

```
        var mouseAtY = e.pageY;
        var mouseAtX = e.pageX;

      if (calHight >= docH)
         {
        tPosX = mouseAtX + 5;
        tPosY = mouseAtY - cntnrH;
         }
 else if (calHight <= calHight){
           tPosX = mouseAtX;
       tPosY = mouseAtY + 15;
      }
      else
      {
       tPosX = mouseAtX;
       tPosY = mouseAtY +20;  
      }
      $zoomContainer.css({top: tPosY, left: tPosX});
      };
     doIt = $("img.hovelble");
     doIt.hover(showZoomImg, hideZoomImg).mousemove(positionImg);
});
```

Comment: your final 'else' will never be executed because '(calHight <= calHight)' will always be true.